# Return data & reference from falcor router

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

I've got a route that returns details about a features on a user's account:

```
// games[{keys:games}].features[{integers:indices}]
{
    $type : "atom",
    value : {
        id: "6",
        count: "1",
        ...
    }
}
```

There's also a route that returns generic details about specific features:

```
// features[{integers:features}]
{
    $type : "atom",
    value : {
        name : "fooga",
        max : 10,
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't want to merge the generic feature data into the user-specific data because that will be a bunch of data duplication, but I also want to be able to get it all in a single request

What's a smart way to structure my routes/returned data so that `games[{keys:games}].features[{integers:indices}]` can return a useful reference to `features[{integers:features}]`?

I tried splitting them up like this:

```
// games[{keys:games}].features[{integers:indices}].details
{
    $type : "atom",
    value : {
        id: "6",
        count: "1",
        ...
    }
}

// games[{keys:games}].features[{integers:indices}].meta
{
    $type : "ref",
    value : [
        "features",
        "15"
    ]
}
```

but I couldn't figure out a way to resolve the `.meta` reference w/o writing redundant-seeming paths like `...features.0.meta.[name,max,...]`. Ideally the ref would just return an atom because it's a small amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up structuring it like this:

```
games[{keys:games}].features[{integers:indices}].details
games[{keys:games}].features[{integers:indices}].feature
features[{keys:games}][{integers:features}].details
```

Ugly paths, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯